# Which Tools or engines are good for creating the interactive web-based reporting?

Tags: mysql, report, reporting

I want to develop a web site that generate a report which query data in MySQL and let users can filter a data by choose from a dropdown list at the header of table column of report.

Would you please suggest any platform or engine that can do those? I found some such as BIRT and JasperReport but they don't seem like I need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've already tried the most popular open source reporting engines (except Pentaho), so that mostly leaves you with the comercial ones; i recommend you to try several (most offer trials) and see if you can find one that fit your needs, and you can start with [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), which is pretty easy to use as it let you create a report with pure drag and drop, from query to design, and can handle filters and parameters the way you want to.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.